# PGP Package Recommendations

Tags: encryption, pgp

I need to use a client's public key to encrypt some csv files as part of an automated package in a windows 2003 domain. Can anyone recommend a PGP package (preferably opensource).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, GPG has [windows binaries](http://www.gnupg.org/download/#auto-ref-2).

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

http://www.gpg4win.org/

Comment: Just to make your life easier:  once your public key is created or imported; all you have to script on the command line is: gpg -e -r {recipient} file.name.csv   --- this will output your gpg encrypted file.